# How to attach a favicon.ico to a Web App built with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Any ideas on How to attach a favicon.ico to a Web App built with Google Apps Script?

EDIT 1: Using UiApp

Thanks, Fausto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the only way to do this is to embed your app in a blank Google Site, and take the following steps:

1. Navigate to the Attachment management section of your site (More Actions | Manage Site | Attachments)
2. Click Upload
3. Click Browse and select your favicon.ico file
4. Your favicon file must be named "favicon.ico"
5. Choose the option to Upload attachment to / (top-level)
6. Click Upload

Google Apps Script **issue #2005** requests functionality to be able to set the app favicon with a UiApp.setFavicon(url) method. See the following link for more details: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2005

Comment: cool, and feel free to check this as the best answer ;) regards

Answer (score 8):

Google Apps now supports this (as of Nov 2015): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setfaviconurliconurl

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
[…]
</head>
```

[Source](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

Comment: thanks Ikai, sorry I didn't mentioned I am using UiApp > I have no idea where to include that code when using UiApp, do you?

Comment: fyi, this is currently in the google apps script list of issues: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2005